# 2-way data binding not work for me

Tags: html, angularjs, laravel-5

In html file the value of input field updated. And using $scope, first time i am able to assign input field. But when i changed input field in htlm, input field value is changed but in js, console log value not changed. I want to get the updated value in js function.And I am using laravel framework.In practice it works. But my project it does not work. Thank you.

index.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           id="send_amount"
           name="send_amount"
           ng-model="send_amount"
           ng-keyup="calculateReceivedAmount()" required>
</div>
@{{ send_amount }}
```

And my js file

```
var exchange = angular.module('app', []);
exchange.controller('MoneyExchangeController', MoneyExchangeController);
function MoneyExchangeController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.send_amount = 100;
    $scope.calculateReceivedAmount = function () {
        console.log($scope.send_amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code on fiddle and it looks like working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS has problems with binding non-object variables, try binding your input as follows :

index.html

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       id="send_amount"
       name="send_amount"
       ng-model="send_amount.value"
       ng-keyup="calculateReceivedAmount()"
       required />
```

app.js

```
var exchange = angular.module('app', []);
exchange.controller('MoneyExchangeController', MoneyExchangeController);
function MoneyExchangeController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.send_amount = {
        value: 100
    };
    $scope.calculateReceivedAmount = function () {
        console.log($scope.send_amount.value);
    };
}
```